# Necessary and sufficient condition for the foliation to induce a fibration

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, foliations

Suppose that there is a locally integrable foliation on a manifold $M$ such that any of its leaves is not dense in $M$. Does that mean that we can factorize $M$ by this distribution and get a topological space with at least one non-trivial continuous function on it?

Comment: You can always define the space of leaves of any foliation. What specific properties do you want on the space of leaves ? Do you want it to be separated, to be a manifold,...